# Angular 2 Max amount of rows for a Ng Prime data table

Tags: angular

What is the max number of rows for a Ng Prime data table with filtering:
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/filter

When my App is showing a list, it will be a reduced list filtered on a period, so the API only exposes a reduced filtered list, based on a period and then it is shown in the Ng Prime Data Table. This prevents the app from loading ½/1 million rows.

The Prime Data Table will then do a more detailed search in the reduced data set.

What is the max recommended amount of rows for a Ng Prime data table ?

Then the API will only expose the max number of rows the Prime Data Table can handle.

Comment: Please click on all the tags you added to this question. Read the info. Do you actually use all? Please correct the tagging

Comment: I have removed the Angular 2 tag, I just thought it was a relative and helpful association.

Comment: you removed the wrong one

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with 5 columns and 90000 rows and that works just fine, but a bit slow.

**Test specs**:

IE 11

Angular 5.0.2

primeng 5.0.2

When you pass the 100.000 rows I would suggest to start using lazy loading(https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/lazy).

I don´t think there is a concrete answer to this question.